# Installing bpy module through pip in python wont give autocompletion/suggestions in VScode

Tags: python

I was trying to setup vscode for writing blender scripting, I installed bpy module for my python using

`pip install bpy`

But still **I wont get autocompletion/suggestions** while writing code (like we get for numpy and matplotlib etc., e.g. we just have to write "numpy." , just after writing dot "." it automatically shows a list of possible functions available to use)

I have heard about `fake-bpy-module` , which can solve this problem.

I uninstalled `bpy` using `pip uninstall bpy` and installed `fake-bpy-module-3.4` using `pip installed fake-bpy-module-3.4`

**Now I am getting the suggestions as I wanted.**
[image: after fake-bpy-module]

*But I am a little confused, the `bpy` module was around 200 MB to download, and this `fake-bpy-module` is just some 0.8 MB but still it gets the work done. HOW??*

Also I forgot to tell, that I installed an extension named *blender development* on vscode

(but I have blender version 3.4.1 and fake-bpy-module version 3.4.1 is not available, fake-bpy-module version 3.4 is available, I installed that (any problem ??))

Comment: Hello ! My guess is that the fake module only contains the definition of the functions and their signature, but you can't do anything with it similar to https://github.com/Korchy/blender_autocomplete/blob/master/3.4/addon_utils.py. The bpy module can be used standalone and I think it's using C / C++ bindings that obfuscate the function signatures for autocomplete. IMO [this how-to](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-microsoft-visual-studio-code-as-external-ide-for-writing-blender-scripts-add-ons/) is still the most straightforward for blender python developement using Vscode.

Comment: AFAIK there is no breaking change in the API between v3.4.0 and 3.4.1 so you should be safe to use 3.4.0

Comment: Install the "Blender Development" extension by Jacques Lucke. It's simply amazing!

Comment: Thanks All !,@Gorgious actually I have a extension named "Blender Development" installed on VScode and I don't have bpy installed in python but I have fake bpy installed. Now everything is working fine as I want, So can I assume that the extension I installed on VScode already contain the bpy module for my python(and I dont need to install it)

Comment: @Psyonic I have it already installed (I have also mentioned the same in my question), I am a newbie to blender, but just for writing some scripts to automate my work, I thought to do it using vscode, as I do everything else there.